# I/O redirection in a while loop

Tags: bash, loops, sh, io-redirection

What is the difference between the following two blocks of code in reading the content of a file?

```
while read i; do 
    echo $i
done < ${filename}
```

```
while read i < ${filename}; do 
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: `< ${filename}` in either example is a redirection, not a process substitution as your Subject/Title implies. But I can't answer your Q, it seems possible, but probably something about the subprocess that gets launched to process a `while` loop. Good luck.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @larsks Haven't tried yet. But the answers already explained everything.

Comment: @shellter :) sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* write it that way, but it always reads the first line.

Think of the while loop like this:

1. In the first case:

   1. Connect the file to stdin
   2. Read until a newline
   3. Loop (read the next line)
   4. Disconnect the file
2. In the second case:

   1. Connect the file to stdin
   2. Read until a newline
   3. Disconnect the file
   4. Loop (reconnect the file, read a line, disconnect the file)

Answer (score 9):

`command <filename` opens `filename`, runs `command` with its standard input connected to the file handle it just opened, and then closes the filehandle.

So when you do `while condition; do ... done <filename`, the whole loop is the `command`: it opens the file once before the loop and doesn't close it until the loop finishes. That means all the `read` statements in the loop are applied successively to the same open file, so it reads all the lines of the file.

But when you do `while read < filename; do ... done`, the `command` is just the `read`. So it opens the file, runs `read`, then closes the file ... every time. You wind up just reading the first line of the file over and over again.